ref(firebase.database(), dbPath) <-> firebase.database().ref(dbPath)
I have the following code that I partly found and adapted to my use, and it is working:
const dbPath = 'Root/MyApp/MyCollection',
      dbRef = ref(firebase.database(), dbPath),
      dbRefX = firebase.database().ref(dbPath)

Here dbRef and dbRefX are used in the code coming after the one above to access a realtime database and handle various operations on the DB.
The difference between the two does not look clear. Nevertheless, it does seem to work if I choose to get rid of one and use only the other.
Can somebody explain the difference between dbRef and dbRefX and their use ?

It sort of looks like you're mixing Firebase's modular and compat imports (which I would not recommend). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade. It would help greatly if you could [edit] your question to show where each of ref and firebase are coming from

You're mixing two API syntaxes, that are functionally equivalent.
This is using the modular API that was introduced in SDK version 9:
const db = getDatabase();
ref(db, dbPath),

This is using the namespaced API that is still supported:
const db = firebase.database();
db.ref(dbPath)

The two pieces of code set up a reference to the exact same location in the database, just with different API versions. The first snippet allows bundlers to exclude unused code from your application bundle, which leads to smaller app bundles - and is the reason the modular API was introduced in SDK version 9.
To learn more, see the documentation on upgrading from the namespaced API to the modular API.
